# Proper way to access the container from a class not in a slim controller

Tags: slim

I have a regular php class outside of a controller, so it doesn't benefit from automatic injection of container. I need to access the response object from that class, and I guess I should get it from the container.
What's the proper way to access it  ? Just pass it as argument so the outside class can use it ? Is there a better way ?

Comment: why do you need the response object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to send a subrequest, Slim [provides such functionality](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1366). Use it [carefully](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1366#issuecomment-211612716) though, as in some situations its result is not obvious.

```php
<?php
class MySortOfOutsideClass
{
    /**
     * If you need to send a subrequest, you have to access application instance,
     * so let's inject it here.
     */
    public function __construct(\Slim\App $app)
    {
        $this->$app = $app;
    }

    /**
     * Method that makes a subrequest, and returns the result of it.
     */
    public function myMethod()
    {
        if ($subRequestIsRequired) {
            return $this->app->subRequest('GET', '/hello');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use middleware for that because the response object is immutable so "changing" it will not update the response which will be used by slim.

```
$app->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    if($shouldRedirect === true) {
        return $response->withRedirect('myurl'); // do not execute next middleware/route and redirect
    }
    return $next($request, $response); // execute next middleware/ the route
});
```

For more information about middleware [have a look at this](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html).

Comment: Thanks, will investigate this. Quick question please: is it possible to trigger the slim route process (which will trigger middleware) from an 'external' file, one that is not inside a controller ?

Comment: @RobertBrax I dont understand, you trigger the execution with `$app->run();`

Comment: Yes, the app is running fine, but I want to trigger the request process from a class file that is not in a controller. Imagine I have a file "authRequired.php" file that is not in a controller but still must be able to do the redirect from inside itself.

Comment: @RobertBrax `but I want to trigger the request process from a class file that is not in a controller` controller do not trigger anything, I dont get what you mean.